# Developing Local Zend Applications with LAMP on Ubuntu - Virtual Host Configurations

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, zend

I have several ZF projects running or closed, however, and until today, I always work directly on the remote server.

I would like to switch to a local environment while developing, so I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to share with me, some virtual host configurations that we should apply on this cases?

The point will be to have:
www/myproject1 folder pointing to: http://myproject1/
www/myproject2 folder pointing to: http://myproject2/
www/myproject3 folder pointing to: http://myproject3/

Any help please?

ps- *I see a lot of examples, but when I add Zend to the query, I seem to have troubles.*

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the following on my ubuntu:

1. Install the zend-framework package with aptitude
2. Add the path to the zend framework in the include path variable of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
3. set-up 3 projects `myproject1`, `myproject2` and `myproject3` inside `/var/www` using `zf create project`
4. In `/etc/apache/sites-available`, I have added 3 files (`myproject1`, `myproject2` and `myproject3`) containing the following:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName myproject1.example.com
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject1/public
>
>   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
>
>   <Directory /var/www/myproject1/public>
>     DirectoryIndex index.php
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

5. Activate them using `a2ensite myproject1`, add the rewrite module with `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache.
6. And finally, I have added the 3 following lines in my `/etc/hosts`:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 myproject1.example.com
> 127.0.0.1 myproject2.example.com
> 127.0.0.1 myproject3.example.com
> ```

And now, I can reach my projects using the URLs http://myproject1.example.com/

If that still does not work for you, would you like please to edit your question with the error messages you get in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: @uloBasEl: That's an outstanding way of working. :) I cannot try  at the moment but that's exactly what I wish and dream about. If I add to all that the git and xdebug I will save it as my holy grail stuff, however, I'm far from learning those two last points. uloBasEl, you rock. Thanks. Cheers!

Comment: Great Ans Indeed ...